# Errors following first use of Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to use Android Studio (for the first time).

And at the first launch, I have a lot of errors regarding the plugins (see screen copy).

How to solve them?

[image: https://zupimages.net/up/18/17/eeoq.png]

Comment: there is a hint to enable the plugins. go ahead and enable them